# Clock in Javascript is not displaying the correct time

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make a clock in Javascript where the user can pick a timezone from a drop down menu, then click submit. Then the correct time will be displayed.

I am getting the universal UTC time:

```
var date = new Date();
var h = date.getUTCHours(); // 0 - 23
var m = date.getUTCMinutes(); // 0 - 59
var s = date.getUTCSeconds(); // 0 - 59
```

Then I am declaring both time, and the timezone value from the drop down menu:

```
function showTime(){

    var time;
    var timezone = document.getElementById('timezone').value;
```

Then depending on the timezone, the hour is supposed to change, and the new time is supposed to be updated

```
    if (timezone.value == "Central"){
    time = (h-5) + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}else if(timezone.value == "Eastern"){
    time = (h-4) + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}else if(timezone.value == "Pacific"){
    time = (h-7) + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}else if(timezone.value == "Mountain"){
    time = (h-6) + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}
```

And in order to make the clock into 12 hour format, I've don't math on the hours again to update the time according to if it is PM or AM

```
if(h > 12){
   time = (h-12) + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    document.querySelector('#sign').textContent = "PM"; 
}else if (h = 12 ){
    time = (12) + ":" + m + ":" + s;    
    document.querySelector('#sign').textContent = "AM";
} else{
    document.querySelector('#sign').textContent = "AM";   
}
```

And then finally, I print out the time, in the correct div:

```
 document.querySelector('#time').textContent = time;

 // When submit is clicked, correct time is displayed, depending on timezone
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
       setInterval(showTime, 1000);
       console.log('clicked');
   });
```

This is my HTML:

```
<body>
<h2>Clock</h2>
<form id="myForm">
    <label for="timezone">Choose a timezone:</label>
    <select id="timezone" name="timezone">
        <option value="Central">Central</option>
        <option value="Eastern">Eastern</option>
        <option value="Pacific">Pacific</option>
        <option value="Mountain">Mountain</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </form>
<div class="time">
    <h1 id="time"></h1>
    <h3 id="sign"></h3>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: What time do you actually get and what time do you expect to get?

Comment: (var timezone = document.getElementById('timezone').value;) `timezone` is a string.  `<string>.value === something` doesn't make sense

Comment: Also `if (h = 12 )` should be `if (h == 12 )` or `if (h === 12 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a great exercise to play around with dates and times. There's a couple of things I'd point out though.

Using a fixed offset from UTC won't work for a lot of timezones. For example Pacific time varies between UTC - 8:00 and UTC -7:00 (during Daylight Saving Time). Also, dates that timezones switch between standard time and daylight saving time vary each year. For example, currently, the Pacific Timezone changes to DST on the second Sunday in March and returns to standard time on the first Sunday in November.

So, it's usually best to use standardized rules for converting Dates to different timezones. Thankfully JavaScript can do some of this for you. You can specify a timeZone identifier using the function [Date.toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

This approach also saves you a lot of coding, you don't have to build up the date yourself.

It's also easy to add new timezones, say Tokyo or Sydney to the dropdown. The list of possible timezones is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones/

```js
setInterval(showTime, 1000);

function showTime() {
    var date = new Date();
    // Get the timezone the user has selected
    var timeZone = document.getElementById('timezone').value;
    // Format the time according to US rules and in the selected timezone
    var time = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone  });
    document.querySelector('#time').textContent = time;   
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h2>Clock</h2>
    <form id="myForm">
        <label for="timezone">Choose a timezone:</label>
        <select id="timezone" name="timezone">
            <option value="America/Chicago">Central</option>
            <option value="America/New_York">Eastern</option>
            <option value="America/Los_Angeles">Pacific</option>
            <option value="America/Denver">Mountain</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <div class="time">
        <h1 id="time"></h1>
    </div>
<body>
```